# Custom Dialog not displaying - Android

Tags: android, dialog, customdialog

I'm trying to pop up a custom dialog when I click on a button but it won't pop up at all. my app is basically a calendar and I'm going to use sqlite to add/hold appointments and stuff to a date in the calendar using the dialog, which is where the appointment details will be specified.

The code I'm using for this is the following:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //long a = calendar.getDate();
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.createButton:
            openCreateAppointmentDialog();
            break;
        }
    }

    private void openCreateAppointmentDialog(){
        Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
        Dialog createAppmntDialog = new Dialog(mContext);

        createAppmntDialog.setContentView(R.layout.create);
        createAppmntDialog.setTitle(R.string.createTitle);

        appointmentTitle = (EditText) createAppmntDialog.findViewById(R.id.titleTextBox);
        appointmentTitle.setText("hello");

        appointmentTime = (EditText) createAppmntDialog.findViewById(R.id.timeTextBox);

        appointmentDetails = (EditText) createAppmntDialog.findViewById(R.id.detailsTextBox);

        saveAppointment = (Button) createAppmntDialog.findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
        saveAppointment.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the [`show()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#show%28%29) method for your dialog.

```
createAppmntDialog.show(); //when you want the dialog to appear on the screen
```

Comment: thanks that worked hehe, but i got a runtime exception so something must be wrong in my code

Comment: @AZ1 And the `RuntimeException` is saying ...?

Comment: 04-20 09:16:03.286: E/AndroidRuntime(1188): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Comment: I removed the context from the dialog and just said ...new Dialog(this); and it worked, but is this safe for wanting to take the users input and store it in an sqlite database?

Comment: @AZ1 A dialog will not work with the application context, it's tied to the activity where is created and shown. It is safe to use `this`, there are no problems.

Comment: its weird though, on the android dev website it shows a tutorial where they want you to use context: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html, but maybe its for a different sort of app or somethin?

Comment: @AZ1 Well, the `Dialog` constructor requires a `Context` reference, just that it will not work with an `Application Context`. By passing `this`(with `this` you are referring to the current activity where you build the dialog) you are providing the current activity `Context` and this will work.